# XSLT query Umbraco

Tags: xslt, content-management-system, umbraco

I am trying to display a list of product on my products page. Product have a productImage, productTitle, productdescription and productImage.

The code below works for title and description but can't display product image. Please help.

Its in umbraco and xslt.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"     
    xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon"    
    xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" 
    xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" 
    xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" 
    xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" 

    xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets" xmlns:Examine="urn:Examine" 
exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon 
    Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions 
    Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets Examine ">

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

    <xsl:variable name="mediaFolderId" select="number($currentPage/mediaFolderId)" />

    <xsl:template match="/">

      <xsl:variable name="mediaId" select="number($currentPage/data[@alias='mediaId'])" />
      <xsl:variable name="mediaNode" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($mediaId, 0)" />
      <img src="{$mediaNode/data[@alias='umbracoFile']}" alt="[image]" height="{$mediaNode/data[@alias='umbracoHeight']}" width="{$mediaNode/data[@alias='umbracoWidth']}" />

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Do you have any data in the mediaId? 
<textarea>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$mediaId" />
</textarea>

Comment: Can you make sure that your mediaID holds a value?
If so, check its value and see if it is a correct integer value or have any spaces around it?

Comment: thanks, I solved the query. mediaId was returning null.